# python pandas - how to apply a normalise function to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, output similar to below:

```
index    value
0    5.95
1    1.49
2    2.34
3    5.79
4    8.48
```

I want to get the normalised value of each column['value'] and store it in a new column['normalised'] but not sure how to apply the normalise function to the column...

my normalising function would look like this: 
    (['value'] - min['value'])/(max['value'] - min['value']

I know I should probably be using the apply or transform function to add the new column to the dataframe but not sure how to pass the normalising function to the apply function...

Sorry if I'm getting the terminology wrong but I'm a newbe to python and in particular pandas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are pretty standard column operations:

```
>>> (df.value - df.value.min()) / (df.value.max() - df.value.min())
0    0.638054
1    0.000000
2    0.121602
3    0.615165
4    1.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

You can simply write

```
df['normalized'] = (df.value - ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets call your DataFrame DF.

```
DF['normalised'] = (DF['value']-min(DF['value']))/(max(DF['value']-min(DF['value'])
```

does the trick.

Comment: This won't work the type you're passing to `min` and `max` are pandas `Series` and this will raise a `ValueError` as the types are array-like and so won't understand this type

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider user the lambda/apply method, which I'm sure you'll be able to finesse, which requires determining ahead of time the min and max values.

First, write a function that outputs a value, based on some 'global' parameters, and an input value fetched from a data-row.

```
def norm(vmax, vmin, val):
    return (val-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)
```

Next, collect your global values from the dataframe:

```
val_min = df['value'].min()
val_max = df['value'].max()
```

Finally, you can apply the function, creating a new field to hold the result:

```
df['new_field'] = df.apply(lambda row : norm(val_min,val_max,row['value']),axis=1)

df
    value   new_field
0   5.95    0.361946
1   1.49    1.000000
2   2.34    0.878398
3   5.79    0.384835
4   8.48    -0.000000
```

The beauty of using this 'lambda' approach, you can tweak your functions as you like, which (in my opinion anyway) compartmentalise the code better, allowing for reuse - which is always a good thing.